# Accessing Data from outside a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, restangular

I'm working with angular and restangular, trying to define a default header I've gotten from my API.

The Token var is never defined with the final Token. I understand why, more or less. But I haven't figured out a way to get that value out of the promise. I've tried scopes, and what not. I've tried calling the default headers inside the promise. This snippet below show a few random attempts combined.

```
 angular
    .module('app')
    .run(function (Restangular, TokenService) {
        var Token;
        TokenService.get().then( function(data) {
               console.log(data.data); //The Correct Token from API
               Token = data.data;
               return data.data;
            }
        );

        Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({
            'X-XSRF-TOKEN': Token  //Token is undefined

        });
    });
```

How can this be done correctly?

Comment: angular and rectangular :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the following code will resolve the JavaScript problem of using closure variables. It will call `Restangular` to set the header values.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .run(function (Restangular, TokenService) {
       TokenService.get().then( function(data) {
           Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({
               'X-XSRF-TOKEN': data.data 
           });
        }
    );
});
```

But, what is wrong with this approach?

TokenService is an asynchronized service, and Angular will start to get the token and continue to initialize the application. It's possible that a directive or service using `Restangular` will try to perform an operation that requires that header token before `TokenService.get(...)` is finish!

There are three possible solutions.

- ignore the problem.
- use a state variable to indicate if the token has been set, and wait for it to be set
- get the token before angular is started.

To get the token first. You'll have to use the TokenService (which I don't know what it is) before angular is started.

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function(){
        // first get token
        TokenService.get().then(function(data){
            // put the token somewhere
            window.token = data.data;
            // then start angular
            angular.bootstrap(document,['myApp']);
        });
 });
```

Now you can use the token when angular starts.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .run(function (Restangular) {
        Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({
           'X-XSRF-TOKEN': window.token
        });
    );
});
```

What `TokenService` is, how you get it before angular starts and if you should put things into `window` aren't really the point of the answer. I'm just trying to make sure you understand that there is a *lag* between when the app starts and when the token will be set. So it's best to do that first.

Comment: You're right. Thank you for your detail and thought. It's true, the asynchronous nature of the request was causing problems since angular needed the value right away. While I had wrestled many hours prior to posting my question, it was clearly the wrong way to go about it. I ditched the token service for a more direct ajax request which was not based on promises. (Now I can't say i quite know the difference), but the problems were instantly resolved and all was good. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @csduarte I've gotten around this problem using ui-route's support for resolve and child views. I create a parent route for `/` for all other child routes. That parent must resolve a promise to get the token before it starts. This creates a basic startup promise for the entire app.

Answer (score 2):

Move the access of Token inside the Promise. The .then of the promise is run sometime after .run as completed, which is why Token is undefined. There is NO way to change this behavior.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .run(function (Restangular, TokenService) {
        TokenService.get().then( function(data) {
               console.log(data.data); //The Correct Token from API
               var token = data.data;
               Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({
                   'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token 
               });
               return data.data;
            }
        );

    });
```

Comment: Also worth noting that this still won't run because `token` is misspelled. `token != Token`

Comment: Correct, and I also did not have the setter actually inside .then function

Comment: Typos weren't part of the actual code, just introduced when i retyped for clarity. I tried this approach, and Rectangular was no longer recognized inside the promise.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing that you need the token for is calling setDefaultHeaders you should be able to do that directly in the then call like:

```
    TokenService.get().then( function(data) {
        Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({
             'X-XSRF-TOKEN': data.data
            });
    });
```

If you need to make the token available throughout the application I guess you could inject '$rootScope' in your 'run' call and then inside 'then' you can assign it like:

```
$rootScope.Token = data.data;
```

This should make Token available wherever you inject $rootScope; do keep in mind that adding stuff to the $rootScope is usually not the best idea.